# What are all the kafka producer properties?

Tags: apache-kafka

Just new to kafka.
Today i was running some commands of kafka-console-producer.sh, i was using key value pair messages

> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic producer-demo  --property
> "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:" --broker-list
> kafka1:9092

i am just curious where we can find producer property like i search
`**"parse.key=true"**` and
`**"key.separator=:"**` in
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs
There is no parameter like this is this custom parameter or predefined because i have to use this more and i can apply on this command

Comment: what is your kafka client?

Comment: there is no as such client basically i was testing this i want to send the producer message in same partition using bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic producer-demo  --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:" --property "partition=1" --broker-list kafka1:9092 but i didn't work my question is the parse.key and key.separator where all these parameter defined so that i can learn it and do some practical

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters in particular are not Producer properties (which you pass with `--producer-property`, and not `--property`). They are CLI arguments that you can really [only find in the source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.8.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L209-L213).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the all properties of kafka producer in the [ProducerConfig class](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.java)

Answer (score 0):

For a handy reference, let me list down the available arguments for kafka-console-producer. I hope you are looking for something like this;

1. `–batch-size <Integer: size>`:- We are defining the single batch for sending the Number of messages
2. `–broker-list <String: broker-list>`: -This is required options for the Kafka-console- producer, the broker list string in the form HOST: PORT
3. `–compression-codec [String: compression-codec]`:- This option is used to compress either ‘none’ or ‘gzip’.If specified without a value, then it defaults to ‘gzip’
4. `–Help:` – It will display the usage information.
5. `–metadata-expiry-ms<Long: metadata expiration interval>`:- The period in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven’t seen any leadership changes. (Default: 300000).
6. `–producer-property <String: producer_prop>`:-This parameter is used to set user-defined properties as key=value pair to the producer.
7. `–producer.config<String: config file>`:-This is the properties file containing all configuration related to the producer.
8. `–property <String: prop>`:- This attribute provides the liberty to pass user-defined properties to the message reader. These properties allow custom configuration and defined in the form of key=value.
9. `–request-required-acks<String: request required acks>`:- The required acks of the producer requests (default: 1)
10. `–request-timeout-ms<Integer: request timeout ms>`:- The ack timeout of the producer Value must be non-negative and non-zero (default: 1500).
11. `–Sync`: – If a set message sends, requests to the brokers are synchronous, one at a time as they arrive.
12. `–timeout <Integer: timeouts>`:- If set and the producer is running in asynchronous mode, this gives the maximum amount of time a message will queue awaiting sufficient batch size. The value is given in ms.
13. `–topic <String: topic>`:- this option is required .basically, the topic id to produce messages to.
14. `–Version`: -Display Kafka version.